# ImportError: cannot import name 'speech_v1beta1'

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, google-cloud-speech

I've installed google-cloud with pip, and that error occurs when I write

```
from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1
```

While it's all ok (but I cannot obviously use the beta features) when I write

```
from google.cloud import speech
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade your `google-cloud-speech` library by running:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech
```